# PHP - reassign Array to String with Square bracktes

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

Is there any simple way to reassign my array (`$newarray`) which output is `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 )` to a simple string like this `[1, 3]` (only the values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create a JSON out of that, because it is a string.

```php
$a = [1,3];
echo json_encode(array_values($a));
```

will output

> [1,3]